# High CPU Use -Bash Process

Tags: bash, cpu-load

I can't seem to figure out why a bash process is sucking up nearly all the cpu capacity. It only recently started doing this. How do I trouble shoot this? I see some articles talking about killing the underlying program but when I open it in the tree format (using htop), it's owner root and it falls under /sbin/init. A few screenshots below of the htop screen.

I'm just not sure where to start with this. I've tried rebooting. I've tried shutting down, unplugging, and restarting from nothing (which is all the typical corporate IT basic things to try).

Running Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a bug in your `bash` startup files that starts `bash` then does something silly. Check your`bash` startup files. Read `man bash` to find out which files.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you but I don't even know what I'm looking at to be honest. I've tried combing through this and even when I get to the bash script files, I'm not even sure where to start.